# File Uploading in Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, multipartform-data

I referred [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet?noredirect=1&lq=1) guide to upload the files with multipart/form-data using Servlet.

1. Before using

   @WebServlet("/upload")

   @MultipartConfig

Annotations I am able to upload the file to the server but unable to read control field data. Now I used Annotations with my Servlet with the action control.

Problem is able to read the control field values but files is not uploading into server. Used this snippets

```
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
//Create a new file upload handler
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
File uploadedFile;
//Parse the request
List  items = upload.parseRequest(request);
Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
}
```

I am getting the **itmes** size as 0 (ZERO) when I pasre the request while uploading the file. What may be the issue in my case ?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP request can be parsed only once. So, If request.get<>() (request.getParameter(),request.getAttribute()) used prior to upload.parseRequest() this will not work. Make sure you are not having any such usage in your servlet (Check filters as well)

Comment: But in my case,

I need to use 

`request.getParameter()` for fetching the control field value before or after the file upload. Thing I need to get upload the file as well as I need to get the control field values ?

Means I cannot able to do these two functions meanwhile with the same **request** object ?

Comment: Can I get any solutions to achieve to perform  both actions ?

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED!!**

[this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html) resolved the file uploading with **multipart/form-data** and reading multiple control fields from the JSP form pages